# Telegram - ffmpeg - "not optimized for streaming"?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, telegram

I tried to convert my huge video file (recorded with smartphone) with ffmpeg as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 output.mp4
```

Video converts, uploads to Telegram, but cannot play back and stream as usual. Rather, on computer it wants to download the whole video file, on phone I get the following strange error message:

"Video not optimized for streaming. You may need to download it in full to play it"

Which parameter should I use in ffmpeg in order to avoid this?

(I also tried the same with libx264, same issue.)

Comment: Add `-movflags +faststart`.